# Escape all special characters from text file (password)

Tags: linux, bash

How to completely escape all special characters used in password that contained in a text file? The code below still failed for me.

```
pawd=$(cat /var/thepassword.txt)
pawd=$(perl -e 'print quotemeta shift(@ARGV)' "${pawd}")
```

Whenever I fetch the `pawd` into `Duplicity` (`PASSPHRASE="$pawd" duplicity ...`), I get bad passphrase. The password can be in this format:

```
vPP%!t'cNCN&%ND`n~,+@SUP*^?YT6;i/tJ*Fu|D#1m3.=LWX?1
```

Comment: Have you tried `pawd=${pawd@Q}` instead of that perl line?

Comment: Yeah, it's still a bad passphrase

Comment: Then escaping metachars is not the solution you need.

Comment: Why don't you initialize directly? `export PASSPHRASE=$(cat /var/thepassword.txt)`

Comment: That's actually clever, thank you.